Next js & Auth js - Logout bug
Im working on a next js project with authentication using Auth js. I have set up middleware, sign in and sign up with credentials, Neon serverless with prisma (as an adapter), and all of that works perfectly. But I cannot find any solution to one problem that got me stuck in the middle of the project.
So far, I have two logout buttons: one in the "/" page (index) and the other in the dashboard. Each of them is placed in a dropdown menu where user can find it by clicking on their profiles. But somehow, I can log out from the current session when I'm in the index page, and I cannot log out in the "/account/today" page. What I mean by "cannot" is that I actually can, but the ui doesnt change. In the index page when i log out, it updates the ui immediately, but in the user dashboard page (/account/today) when i click to log out, server sends 303 OK Post response, but the ui still gets stuck at pending. The both logout buttons have useFormStatus hook from react-dom to use "pending" state. As you might guess, this state doesn't stop in that specific page, but in the index page it works ok. Both components are almost the same.
I apologize if my english is not good. I have tried my best to explain the situation. Please take your time and help me to solve this bug. If anything is needed, please tell me, I will try to provide the relevant information you need.
This is the server action:
export const logOut = async () => {
  await signOut({ redirectTo: "/" });
};

The middleware.ts:
export default auth(async function middleware(req) {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;
  const isAuthRoutes = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isPublicRoutes = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  const isApiAuthRoutes = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);

  const isAdminRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(adminPrefix);
  const isAdmin = req.auth?.user.role === "ADMIN";

  if (isApiAuthRoutes) {
    if (isLoggedIn)
      return Response.redirect(new URL('/account/today', nextUrl));
    return undefined;
  }

  if (isAuthRoutes) {
    if (isLoggedIn)
      return Response.redirect(new URL('/account/today', nextUrl));
    return undefined;
  }
  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoutes)
    return Response.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", nextUrl));

  if (isAdminRoute) {
    if (!isAdmin) return new Response("Not found", { status: 404 });
  }

  return undefined;
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

auth.ts
export const {
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
  handlers: { GET, POST },
} = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  events: {
    linkAccount: async ({ user }) => {
      await prisma.user.update({
        where: { id: user.id },
        data: {
          emailVerified: new Date(),
          role: user.email === process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL ? "ADMIN" : "USER",
        },
      });
    },
  },

  callbacks: {
    session: ({ token, session, user }) => {
      if (token.sub && session.user) session.user.id = token.sub;
      if (token.role && session.user)
        session.user.role = token.role as UserRole;
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ token, user, session }) => {
      if (!token.sub) return token;
      const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub);
      if (!existingUser) return token;
      token.role = existingUser.role;
      return token;
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  ...authConfig,
});

auth.config.ts
export default {
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    GitHub({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    Credentials({
      authorize: async (credentials, request) => {
        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (!validatedFields.success) throw new Error("Invalid credentials");

        const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;

        const user = await getUserByEmail(email);

        if (user && user.password) {
          const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(
            password,
            user.password,
          );
          if (isPasswordMatched) return user;
          else return null;
        } else return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

component:

<form action={logOut} className='flex flex-col p-2'>
  <SidebarLogout />
</form>

export default function SidebarLogout() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <button
      className='justify-start gap-3 px-2 hover:text-foreground h-10 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 disabled:bg-background-100'
      disabled={pending}
    >
      {pending ? <Spinner /> : <LuLogOut />}
      Log out
    </button>
  );
}


useFormStatus does not seem to work with server actions as stated in this link: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49232
Please try the following suggested workaround;
1) Place your action and form in a server component
"use server"

import SidebarLogout from "@/components/SidebarLogout" // change the path

export const logOut = async () => {
  await signOut({ redirectTo: "/" })
}

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <form action={logOut} className='flex flex-col p-2'>
            <SidebarLogout />
        </form>
    )
}

2) SideBarLogout should be a client component
"use client"

export default function SidebarLogout() {
    const { pending } = useFormStatus()

    return (
        <button className='justify-start gap-3 px-2 hover:text-foreground h-10 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 disabled:bg-background-100' disabled={pending}
        >
            {pending ? <Spinner /> : <LuLogOut />}
            Log out
        </button>
    )
}

Here's a working git repo as a reference: https://github.com/techulus/manage-prompt/blob/c9dad49a802c2192d1553d62e4b3151dda134fdf/app/console/workflows/new/page.tsx#L7
